# compose generic type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How do I compose an object in a generic function satisfying a desired output type when passing some fields as arguments?

I am doing this because I want to encapsulate a pattern in my Nodejs code.

Here is what I'm attempting:

```js
interface RBAC {
    owners: Array<string>
}

interface Resource extends RBAC {
    id: string
}

interface Model extends Resource {
    name: string
}

type ModelArgs = Omit<Model, "id" | "owners">

const makeModelExplicit = (args: ModelArgs, userId: string): Model => {
    return {
        id: "456",
        owners: [userId],
        ...args,
    }
}

const args: ModelArgs = {
    name: "test",
}

const modelExplicit = makeModelExplicit(args, "user-123")

// TODO: Why won't this compile?

// const makeModelGenericReturn = <M extends Resource, ArgsT = Omit<M, "id" | "owners">>(args: ArgsT, userId: string): M => {
//     const model: M = {
//         id: "456",
//         owners: [userId],
//         ...args,
//     }

//     return model
// }

// const modelGenericReturn = makeModelGeneric<Model>(args, "user-123")

// TODO: or this?
// const makeModelGeneric = <ArgsT, M = ArgsT & Resource> (args: ArgsT, userId: string): M => {
//     const model = {
//         id: "456",
//         owners: [userId],
//         ...args,
//     }

//     return model
// }

// const modelGenericArgs = makeModelGeneric(args, "user-123") as Model
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQCUBCBBAwqgb2FRNQHsB3MWAZwC5VsYYEBPAHhohnAHMA+YAF9goSLEQoMUGmQCuMKVAAe0MABMaGHPiKlUIdQy48wvYaPDR4yNAFky6qABtUKtZumyFUvaTAIALZQxtx8FsAQrAAO9o4uTLxaALyoAPKBIBDsDk7OADSoAESGRagAPsWU1DA0RYLASGRgXKiBCADWULkuAKLK0c4gSFmoqQAUCDBJDD3OiTSFcjSwAJJGqCZ8AJSz8a7J-ITEpDBQEApgx-r6hgxFACwArABsRfknN+RUtAwA2ss1uoALofL4kAB0UKmSTBpBEIkazVaMPoqDmCzG138QRCxWgXHeESaLQgbX2-UGw1GqXaXTmlKGIwgk2mi2KgJgAFoAIwAJgAzEVtqIAPSi1AAFTSABE0gwAOoAC1YqAozQA5GSIEqQFomoFoiBnFAAPxiiUk1p07r7ADiUBqw3Q50uWJyblUjs8Lu8iighQWkqxGSyOUKJXUZUqRWqtHq-FZM0YbMlSxWMHWoVMvF26LGRyI4puVrJgX2syxRYl4IMG0eryJxdrcdq-0561BwGb4KhENRHx7JERQ9QZwuMCu5by3YlI8tyLL9sdsGdrsnWJtcwdTqQOX2iYHHIzvMFwotUtl8vIMFQOr15uLpbanVteR3q6Q7qDhTsWKDqAAGRePI-pHEmaI-qgHYbFsZh5n+hzHKOz7Ti4VazrWdb3M8byDjW4KtmiAIZp2+FYX2A6Yfo843OObpoc4mG0ahy67pitKvtuK48EgEERpyp5CtsqAIFoczAEAA)

Comment: Is your actual question hidden in a code comment?  Are you asking "why won't this compile" or are you asking "how can I write this function"?  The answer to the first is that `ArgsT` just *defaults* to `Omit<M, ...` and it can be anything the caller wants.  And so can `M`.  The caller can write `makeModelGeneric<string, number>(...)`. So the compiler really cannot be sure that `{id: "456", ....` will be of type `M`.   The answer to the second is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDRl8W) where you just let the compiler infer the type of `args` and add stuff to it.  Does that address your ...

Comment: ... question fully?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah, i'll improve it.

Comment: @jcalz it was hidden, now I've asked a proper question; how do I compose an object in a generic function satisfying a desired output type?

Comment: @jcalz your playground implementation is what I was after. thank you!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get the chance.

Comment: @jcalz one improvement I was initially looking for was a way to specify the return type so the caller knows what they are getting. If you know a way to do that, it would be great because sometimes I've found it helpful to have a return type specified, e.g. when returning a Promise<T>. In this implementation the return type is figured out by TS, but the caller doesn't get any control or guarantee.

Comment: The playground link shows that you can just annotate the receiving variable as your expected type.  If it works, great; if not, [the error explains what's wrong](https://tsplay.dev/NdYQym).  Any alternative would still presumably involve the caller writing out the expected type, but it would probably be more awkward.  `const foo: Bar = baz(qux)` is, in my opinion, superior to `const foo = baz<Bar>(qux)` .  So I'm not sure what you'd prefer to see here.

Comment: you could simply cast https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoCECCBhZBvAewHcRoBnALmUyijgE8AeMsKUAcwD4BfAKFEixEKVBDIEArlCTIIAD0ggAJmTRZceYEqos2IdnwHR4MgLIElEADayFEZatHipMvCDgBbCDtYc+CAhAWZA84AGsIc0srAHF7aGAEAF5GU1tFFTQxSWkITgAKOCh2SgB5D2AwVIAaAHItWoAfWuJSKDJazmqJMmgASW1dDgBKCjSkznxeZGQoCDApEHwtClqARgAmAGZa6tbyCgBtHv6lAF1qgDpropLuZDhVNIB6Z+QyAAtJKyVkACMUGQ4DAILw+K9kAQoLwAkEwCFwpELNY4m1EgA5AjYR5gFJpeQZRzZFx5QrFSjIcqVGr1JRNFokcidarIE5QAY+PTsUZUqqmOoNZr7dqdABkAAVEmEaYKGW0OpMJlMZnMFlAlpptOttrthZRjr12ecrjdyXx-IFxFYIJcrAR2PlQhEoij4mwEPk3J5vLUAA7zaC1bh1X1rWrDYZAA

Comment: @zapl you say "should be safe", and often it would be, but [it is not necessarily so](https://tsplay.dev/Nr4RoW).

Comment: @jcalz oh yes, that's the way to break it. I think you would be safe exactly when you you're not allowed to subtype the `id` or `users` properties on `Resource`. But I guess using your `A extends object` code is superior in the end, that gives a nice compile time error in that case.

Comment: To reiterate: I'm still waiting on @cyrf to tell me what they want to see here, since, in my judgment, it is better to just annotate the variable you initialize instead of manually specifying a generic type parameter.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for showing the error that will occur if a caller requests the wrong type. I agree with your judgement. Please write an answer so I can approve it!

Comment: Okay I will do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is unsound because [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function type parameters are specified by the *caller* of the function and not the *implementer*.  The caller could decide to specify any `M` they want that is a subtype of `Resource`, regardless of the value passed in for `args`.  Additionally, your `ArgsT` type parameter merely [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `Omit<M, keyof Resource>`; it is not [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

The simplest functioning implementation of `makeModelGeneric` is probably this:

```
const makeModelGeneric = <A extends object>(args: A, userId: string) => {
    const model = {
        id: "456",
        owners: [userId],
        ...args,
    }

    return model
}
```

which has the inferred call signature of

```
/* const makeModelGeneric: <A extends object>(args: A, userId: string) => {
    id: string;
    owners: string[];
} & A */
```

Meaning that `args` can be absolutely any object, from which the generic type parameter `A` will be inferred, and the return type is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `A` with `{id: string, owners: string[]}` (which is equivalent to `Resource`).

If you want to do that explicitly and be a little more careful about representing the fact that any `name` and `owners` property from `args` will be overwritten, you can do this:

```
const makeModelGeneric = <A extends object>(args: A, userId: string) => {
    const model: { [K in keyof A as Exclude<K, keyof Resource>]: A[K] } & Resource = {
        id: "456",
        owners: [userId],
        ...args,
    }
    return model;
}
/* const makeModelGeneric: <A extends object>(args: A, userId: string) => { 
    [K in keyof A as Exclude<K, keyof Resource>]: A[K]; 
} & Resource */
```

where `{[K in keyof A as Exclude<K, keyof Resource>]: A[K]}` is essentially the same type as `Omit<A, keyof Resource>` except using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) as suggested in [microsoft/TypeScript#41383](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41383).

---

When we call it, this is what happens:

```
const modelGenericArgs = makeModelGeneric(args, "user-123");
/* const modelGenericArgs: {
    name: string;
} & Resource */
```

This is exactly the right type, but it's not explicitly written as `Model`, and if you pass in the wrong `args` it won't complain.  The way to deal with this is to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the variable as being of type `Model`.  If that works, everything is right with the world:

```
const modelGenericArgs: Model = makeModelGeneric(args, "user-123"); // okay
```

And if you make a mistake, you get an error message explaining the problem:

```
const badArgs = { name: false }; // oopsie

const notModelGenericArgs: Model = makeModelGeneric(badArgs, "user-123"); // error!
// -> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
// Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=51&ssc=1&pln=59&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoCECCBhZBvAKGWOQHsB3EaAZwC5lMoo4BPAHmrClAHMA+AgF8CBUJFiIUqCNVIBXKEmQQAHpBAATamiy5CJZMA31O3EDyEix0eEoCypDRAA2ytRE3bpshUv0kQOABbCBMuXksCBFIQTmQ4KB5tAF58IgDg0OQAIkhObIAaSOjYsGQguABrCAcnZwBxD2hgBABGZFS2TDd1LTIAIwArCAQwPgAKBKT6TALkOWpoAEljZFNeAEoOvjSDErigxxcO3YMSI3psgBYAVgA2QvSzskoaegBtBeWNAF0i5+IADpgVNqP8SMInsgoBAwAoQOUjs5LAB6ABUyH2ZQq1VqLkaVG4CHoXR6Hj6pCGIzGk0SdAYcy+UBWYTMPC2yR2-mIFzW4XMAG4oRRCfT1uZ3j8hYJkAAyBjINEokRRGIHKo1JEE5oIE6k1S9bSU4ajCagmaMxbM1bi9nbU7ELGIur0PDId4AaUMCOqLFIMAVcG0AFEVAhnHInGwPXNff60DJ5IoIHwfjNPT9kDL5d4k0pUtyzrzrvdHgCXqKPkyVn8oQZgYDQeDiMIDDC4VAEYc6tKCOjMWrsRq8Q0mkSSd0DeSjVTTbTpgz5laWXy2RyucgoZ7vcg4wHukHkKHw5GINHYxA-QHc74U2mGBmBZvswmfMnFcrVaVnfixy1GEk7SpDimp1NqRLzmCORMgAtK0ABMADM2QbEK-ZOt2v6Ev+dKtK6UKBCErK8NKcqvnmKBKiIGFan+CAAfSI4nCBI7gS0kFzNksEIchqHICiKJkJUrDUYOyD9HAGgMScbqEVk8DOIsWZCl+cQgKQYCsXRDH0ExwHDrR2EIOMElSXSnHcUhKFPgJyhMKQUAAIR9oJME7AAfp5XneT53nIAAKiwAAOMhkAGQVQKQIVQGALDIAA5HJ8XxDC3rREEQVwGAwD9M4ECAi5AXBSg8X9KQpB5XAIDJcA2jqWUQbUMAPCBLlKBgKQyCxSFCW2vFKoEEAA)